# Define Max connection pool size in MongoDB + Java

Tags: java, mongodb

For my Application, I am trying to set min and maximum pool size for the connection. So, Can anyone help me how to do it with mongo Client.

Also not I saw the options through the MOngoClientURI but is there any other option with MongoClientOption or MongoClient.

My Current Code:

```
public void buildMongoClient() {
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(dbHostName, dbPort);
        mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(DATABASE);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
public void buildMongoClient() {
    MongoClientOptions.Builder clientOptions = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
    clientOptions.minConnectionsPerHost();//min
    clientOptions.connectionsPerHost();//max
    mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(dbHostName, dbPort), clientOptions.build);
    mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(DATABASE);
 }
```

Comment: But here I am not getting option to define my own parameters. How to mention the connection pool I want like 500.

Comment: I'm not following you.  `clientOptions.connectionsPerHost(500)` something like this.

Comment: Actually, I want to define the timeout and min max connection pool at time of application startup for mongo db.

Comment: but your post specifically asks about setting it through MongoClientOptions  .Did I miss something ? I'm not sure what kind of application you have.

Comment: Nope. This answer solve my problem. Thanks for the help. Just one more thing. On my system start up I have created only one mongoDatabase and on every concurrent request I am using the same Mongo Dataabse object. So, is connection pool maintained within that object and on concurrent request serviing connection from that pool?

Comment: You just have to test out that part for your specific use case but it should be shared between requests.

Comment: I cannot seem to make this configuration work, whatever value I use for `connectionsPerHost` I get 100 connections for my `mongoTemplate`, @Souvik can you confirm that you got exact amount of connections you specify in `MongoClientOptionsBuilder` ?